# quiero convertir mi base de datos en una variable en django

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, django

estoy consstruyendo una API para un Ecommerce, pero me pidieron que en el home, se muestren los articulos disponibles. como una especie de twitter. Recordé que hice exactamente eso en mi primer proyecto mientras estudiaba, un clon de twitter pero en FastAPI, y en ese momento no sabia nada de bases de datos por lo que hice un .json.

***Este es el codigo :***

```
with open("tweets.json", "r+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        results = json.loads(f.read())
        tweet_dict = tweet.dict()
        tweet_dict["tweet_id"] = str(tweet_dict["tweet_id"])
        tweet_dict["created_at"] = str(tweet_dict["created_at"])
        tweet_dict["update_at"] = str(tweet_dict["update_at"])
        tweet_dict["by"]["user_id"] = str(tweet_dict["by"]["user_id"])
        tweet_dict["by"]["birth_date"] = str(tweet_dict["by"]["birth_date"])
        results.append(tweet_dict)
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(json.dumps(results))
        return tweet
```

Ahora, uso MySQL, y quiero hacer algo parecido.

¿como hago para iterar mi tabla en la base de datos con django?